# Multiple WebViews in ScrollView giving issues (Android)

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

I have a scrollview which has multiple webviews, these webviews are loading some pages.
The problem is that i cannot explain so you have to see [image: this].

The webviews upon scrolling get distorted as shown in the picture. when load for the first time they are ok.

Comment: What do you mean "When load for the first time they are OK?

Comment: @Farhan: Putting anything that can scroll (such as a `WebView`) inside a `ScrollView` is a bad idea. OK, that doesn't exactly help you with your problem but it wouldn't surprise me if it's a contributing factor.

Comment: @Pyrodante means, when start for the first time, everything is fine, the things got bad when i scroll the view up and down

Comment: @Farhan Can we do pinch zoom to each webview in above scenario ?

Comment: I was trying to do some thing back in 2011, but as @Squonk said, its not a good idea so i basically kind of dropped this and would advise u same. Having said that, I am also not sure if pinch zoom is applicable but if scrollview isn't registered to captur the touch events then most probably they will transfer to childs in our case webviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , I got your problem. It happens because android does the caching of the elements available in the scrollview.
You should use caching properly , look out for the methods.Use this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Thanx, that works, but i play a video in one of the webview, the cache thing didn't work on that. The video was getting distort once i move the scroll up... Can you help in that?

Comment: yes thanks for explaining your problem in more detail , but i have not yet tried for video display in webview.

Comment: Can you try whenever you get time and let me know the result cz its a geniune bug... you will see once u try..

Comment: Yes I will surely try to get back to you as soon as possible.But you too keep googling out the things :)

Comment: And one more thing , if possible can you please give me the code for reference so that I can take it forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading each webview sequentially, meaning wait till one loads before loading the next. It might be an issue with it making parallel requests, from what I know regular browsers have limits on the number parallel requests to a given host.

Comment: As i said, when i start the program, they all loads ok. the webviews gets distorted when i start scrolling upward or downward

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell without seeing your XML, however you should be aware that a ScrollView can host only one direct child.

Comment: yes, i have a scrollview whose child is a linearlayout. Now this linearlayout have some webviews as childs.